# ffmpeg parse cropdetect in php error

Tags: php, ffmpeg, crop

so i/m trying to parse the crop detect value from ffmpeg input using php using this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="video"  />
<input type="submit" name="crop" value="crop"/>
 </form>
</body>
<?
if(isset($_POST['crop'])){

$ffmpeg = '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1/bin/ffmpeg';

shell_exec($ffmpeg ." -i ".$_FILES['video']['tmp_name']." -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1
"); 


}
?>
```

but i get an error:

```
Undefined variable: NF
```

I have no clue what to do any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's trying to parse $NF like a PHP variable, which if it is one, you haven't defined it. You might have to escape the dollar sign if it's a shell command

Comment: and how do i go about escaping it? (its a shell command not an undefined php variable)

Comment: try `\$NF` to escape the $ sign

Comment: Made it an answer in case others have the same problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `$` as I said in the comments by adding a `\` => `\$NF`